# Issue Facing after POPUP window closed, parent window element is not able to click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

OS:
Windows 10

Selenium Version:
3.4.0

Browser:
Mozila Firefox

Browser Version:
54.0.1 (64-bit)

GreckoDriver version :
v0.18.0

Description:Issue Facing after POPUP window.Element is not able to click in next window.

ERROR:

POPUP
By.name: btnClose

[13, 25, 50]

---

A coding exception was thrown and uncaught in a Task.

Full message: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Full stack:

---

Code Below:

```
public static File pathBinary = new File("C:\\program files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    public static FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary);

    public static WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
    public static String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Comment: Where is the `POPUP window` in your code block? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the future, provide more code (if possible) so we can better understand what you are trying to do.  It seems like your issue is switching the WebDriver's focus to the original window.  The method I use to do this is:

**Create an array to hold all Window Handles:**

```
ArrayList<String> windowhandlesArray = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
```

**Switch driver focus to the newly opened popup window**

```
driver.switchTo().window(windowhandlesArray.get(1));
```

**Close the popup window**

```
driver.close();
```

**Switch driver focus back to the original window**

```
driver.switchTo().window(windowhandlesArray.get(0));
```

This should help, unless I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make sure that you have switched back to the main window handle try using this after the pop up has been closed.

```
driver.switchTo().window(0);
```

Then try searching for the element

Answer (score 0):

OR you can try:

to switch to the default again.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

to switch to a frame:

```
driver.switchTo.frame("Frame_ID");
```